# Reverse of cropping image in Ruby

Tags: ruby, image, minimagick

Hi I have image where one dimension is smaller than 100px, I need "resize" image in that way where image has this same scale but dimension that is smaller than 100px need have 100px, so basically I need "stretch" background for one dimension of image that is smaller than 100px. As I understand I need create white/transparent image and merge it with my product image, but how to do it with ruby?

Comment: resize / stretch / merge – all of that can be done, but it’s unclear what exactly you want. Can you add example images and the expected results?

Comment: Stretching is not the "reverse" of cropping. At a glance, is this what the `distort` option achieves?